# More perl style Function Templates in python

Tags: python, perl

This is a follow up to [perl style Function Templates in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72307337/perl-style-function-templates-in-python).  Again, I'm the author of [pythonizer](https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer), and automatic perl to python converter, and I'm trying to write generalized code to convert some interesting perl constructs to python, and having some difficulty.  Again, when I generate what I think is the equivalent code, the value of the loop variable is the last value instead of the value that it was when the function template comes into existence, but in other similar cases it IS the last value that I want, not the original value.  Since I love using TDD, let's look at my test case, which I wrote before implementing the solution given in the referenced question:

```
# test function templates per the perlref documentation
use Carp::Assert;

sub _colors {
    return qw(red blue green yellow orange purple white black);
}

my $namemod = 'blue';

for my $name (_colors()) {
    $name2 = $name;
    my $name1 = $name;
    no strict 'refs';
    *$name = sub { $name3 = $name; $name4 = $name2; $name5 = $name1; $name6 = $namemod; $namemod .= 'x'; return "<FONT COLOR='$name'>@_</FONT>" };
    $name1 = "$name$name";
}

$namemod = 'yellow';

assert(red("careful") eq "<FONT COLOR='red'>careful</FONT>");
assert($name3 eq 'red');
assert($name4 eq 'black');
assert($name5 eq 'redred');
assert($name6 eq 'yellow');
assert($namemod eq 'yellowx');
assert(green("light") eq "<FONT COLOR='green'>light</FONT>");
assert($name3 eq 'green');
assert($name4 eq 'black');
assert($name5 eq 'greengreen');
assert($name6 eq 'yellowx');
assert($namemod eq 'yellowxx');

print "$0 - test passed!\n";
```

Here is the equivalent code generated by my current version of pythonizer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Generated by "pythonizer -v0 -m test_function_templates.pl" v0.978 run by JO2742 on Fri Jun 17 17:48:09 2022
# test function templates per the perlref documentation
import builtins, sys, perllib

_str = lambda s: "" if s is None else str(s)
perllib.init_package("main")
# SKIPPED: use Carp::Assert;


def _colors(*_args):
    return "red blue green yellow orange purple white black".split()


_args = perllib.Array()
builtins.__PACKAGE__ = "main"
namemod = "blue"

for name in _colors():
    name2 = name
    name1 = name
    pass  # SKIPPED:     no strict 'refs';

    def _f14(*_args):
        global name2, name3, namemod, name4, name, name1, name6, name5
        name3 = name
        name4 = name2
        name5 = name1
        name6 = namemod
        namemod += "x"
        return f"<FONT COLOR='{name}'>{perllib.LIST_SEPARATOR.join(map(_str,_args))}</FONT>"

    globals()[name] = _f14
    name1 = f"{name}{name}"


namemod = "yellow"

assert _str(red("careful")) == "<FONT COLOR='red'>careful</FONT>"
assert name3 == "red"
assert name4 == "black"
assert name5 == "redred"
assert name6 == "yellow"
assert namemod == "yellowx"
assert _str(green("light")) == "<FONT COLOR='green'>light</FONT>"
assert name3 == "green"
assert name4 == "black"
assert name5 == "greengreen"
assert name6 == "yellowx"
assert namemod == "yellowxx"

perllib.perl_print(f"{sys.argv[0]} - test passed!")
```

This code fails with this error: `assert _str(main.red("careful")) == "<FONT COLOR='red'>careful</FONT>` because it's using the last value of name (black), not the value of name when the function was defined in the loop.  The fixes recommended by [@Cyrille Pontvieux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988874/cyrille-pontvieux) and [@Kamel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7438379/kamel) would both fix this issue, however, they would also fail to get the other values of name3, name4, name5, or namemod correct.  So I'm left trying to understand in which circumstances should I apply the fix (e.g. in the @Cyrille Pontvieux case, passing the value as an argument instead of marking it global, and using the functools.partial on the reference to the function), and which case I should leave my existing generated code alone.

Comment: `$name` and `$name1` are variables scoped to the loop which get closed over. All the others are globals. In your Python you seem to have them all as globals?

Comment: Yeah - python does not have variables that are scoped to a loop, but is that the key to determine which ones I should pass as arguments and use "partial" on?  Though take a look at `$name5` which is based on the value of `$name1` but not on the value of `$name1` when the function is defined, it's based on the value of `$name1` at the bottom of the loop!

Comment: You might be able to wrap the loop body in a dummy function to fake a loop scope. Something like the Python equivalent of `(sub { ... })->();`

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, I don't actually understand this code and why works in Perl, so it's really challenging to make a Python version of it. I was able to get all tests cases to pass but two though.

The remaining two test cases are both ones that I don't understand why they work in Perl. `assert name5 == 'redred'` and `assert name5 == 'greengreen'`

Hope this contains something that at least helps you get a little further along than you were though.

```py
import perllib
from string import Template

global namemod, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6
namemod = ''
name2 = ''
name3 = ''
name4 = ''
name5 = ''
name6 = ''


def _str(s): return "" if s is None else str(s)


perllib.init_package("main")

# sub _colors {
#    return qw(red blue green yellow orange purple white black);
# }


def _colors():
    return "red blue green yellow orange purple white black".split()


# my $namemod = 'blue';
namemod = 'blue'
# for my $name (_colors()) {
for name in _colors():
    # $name2 = $name;
    name2 = name
    # my $name1 = $name;
    name1 = name

    func_template = '''
global namemod, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6
global $name
def $name(*_args):
    global namemod, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6

    name3 = '$name'
    name4 = name2
    name5 = '$name'
    name6 = namemod
    namemod += 'x';
    return f"<FONT COLOR='$name'>{perllib.LIST_SEPARATOR.join(map(_str,_args))}</FONT>"
'''
    func_str = Template(func_template).substitute({'name': name})
    eval(compile(func_str, '<string>', 'exec'))

    # $name1 = "$name$name";
    name1 = f"{name}{name}"

# $namemod = 'yellow';
namemod = 'yellow'

# assert(red("careful") eq "<FONT COLOR='red'>careful</FONT>");
assert red("careful") == "<FONT COLOR='red'>careful</FONT>"

# assert($name3 eq 'red');
assert name3 == 'red'

# assert($name4 eq 'black');
assert name4 == 'black'

# assert($name5 eq 'redred');
# assert name5 == 'redred'

# assert($name6 eq 'yellow');
assert name6 == 'yellow'

# assert($namemod eq 'yellowx');
assert namemod == 'yellowx'

# assert(green("light") eq "<FONT COLOR='green'>light</FONT>");
assert green("light") == "<FONT COLOR='green'>light</FONT>"

# assert($name3 eq 'green');
assert name3 == 'green'

# assert($name4 eq 'black');
assert name4 == 'black'

# assert($name5 eq 'greengreen');
# assert name5 == 'greengreen'

# assert($name6 eq 'yellowx');
assert name6 == 'yellowx'

# assert($namemod eq 'yellowxx');
assert namemod == 'yellowxx'

# print "$0 - test passed!\n";
print('Test passed!')
```

edit: oops, missed a line `name1 = name` - it had no impact on the tests though

Comment: I think you haven't understood the question, re-read it.

Comment: Thanks!  How do I know that only `name` gets templated and not the other vars used in the sub?

Comment: Note - my fix for my original issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72307337/perl-style-function-templates-in-python/73994166#73994166) has also fixed this issue, except for the case of $name5, which I decided not to handle.